# How to get the second <td> data when the first <td> contains your desired value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a for loop to retrieve some data and I am currently stuck. I need to get the second  value when the first  contains "Primary NAICS Code"

```
 <td class="col_left"><strong>Primary NAICS Code</strong></td>
 <td align="left">                                                        

  311811 : Retail Bakeries                                                    
                                                 </td>
```

My for loop which is obviously not working looks like this

```
for i, elem in enumerate(all_trs):
    inside_td = elem.find("td")
    if "NAICS" in inside_td.text:
    inside_td = elem.find("td")
    print(inside_td.text)
```

Really appreciate any help I could  get. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please indent the line(s)? after `if "NAICS" ...` properly, they make a difference. That seems to be your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but instead of:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(all_trs):
    inside_td = elem.find("td")
    if "NAICS" in inside_td.text:
        inside_td = elem.find("td")
        print(inside_td.text)
```

Try this:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(all_trs):
    td_elems = elem.findAll('td')
    if 'NAICS' in td_elems[0].text:
        print(td_elems[1].text)
```

## Explanation:

The `findAll` method returns a list of `td` elements so, just get a handle on this sequence, and you can of course index it :)

> find_all(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs)
>
> Extracts a list of Tag objects that match the given
>         criteria.  You can specify the name of the Tag and any
>         attributes you want the Tag to have.

The `find` method returns only the first `td` element, equivalent to basically: `findAll('td')[0]`

> find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, **kwargs)
>
> Return only the first child of this Tag matching the given
>       criteria.

Answer (score 0):

It is the second next sibling of the `<td>` that contains the string of interest (the immediate next sibling is a line break):

```
import re
...
soup.body.findAll('td', text=re.compile('Primary NAICS Code'))[0]\
         .next_sibling.next_sibling

#<td align="left">                                                        
#
#  311811 : Retail Bakeries                                                    
#                                                 </td>
```